# listener is not working

Tags: oracle, listener

```
LSNRCTL> status
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=abc.domain.com)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   Linux Error: 111: Connection refused
```

I have registered 1518 using following command

```
Alter system register
```

can connect with sql developer using 1518 as port but cannot connect using port 1521

listener.ora file is

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = orcl)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1)
      (SID_NAME = ORCL)
    )
  )
```

tnsnames.ora file is

```
ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = abc.domain.com)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

Comment: Shouldn't you also change the port in tnsnames.ora to 1518?

Comment: Did you restart the Orcale after changing the server?

Comment: Have you modified the listener.ora from 1518 to 1521 while it was running? You haven't shown the part of the file that defines the address and port, so it'll be on 1521 by default. Do you have a different listener, maybe under a different Oracle home, on 1518?

Comment: yes i changed it in tnsnames.ora  but same error @collapsar